# XSLT failing to add spacec in html output , when a node contains other xml nodes and space between them

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am facing an issue in the output of an XSLT 2.0. Here saxon processor used to generate the html output. It was running smoothly. But output html is failed to add space between two "**variable.varref**" elements. I have searched for the xsl:preserve, unfortunately it did not work for me. How to handle this issue. Please suggest?

[image]

```
<note client.key="v925767807">
<content.unit client.key="v925767808">
<para language="en_ww" client.key="v925767809">
You can sign up for an account on <variable.varref variable.name="eprint_center"/> <variable.varref variable.name="eprint_center_retire2"/>,  and sign in to configure the test settings.
</para>
</content.unit>
</note>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant part of the XSLT you are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be many reasons for this, but the two avenues to pursue are (a) the space isn't present in the source tree, because it has for some reason been stripped during parsing, and (b) the space is present in the source tree but your code isn't outputting it. Without seeing any of your code, it's not really sensible to speculate any further, but:

(a) can occur because you have used a parser configured to strip "insignificant" whitespace, or because of xsl:strip-space in the stylsheet, or because of various Saxon configuration options like -strip:all, or because there is a DTD or schema that defines para to have element-only content (which in this case is unlikely, because the source document would be invalid against this DTD/schema).

(b) might occur because your processing didn't select all the text nodes, or because it called normalize-space() on them, or as a result of a million other possible bugs in your code.

I would suggest reducing it to a small reproducible example, then posting your (minimal) source document and stylesheet in complete form, together with details of how you are invoking the transformation.

Comment: I was using strip:all in command line argument. I removed that and it is working fine. This can also be fixed by adding xml:space="preserve" attribute to the above para tag. Please suggest is there in any drawback by using strip:all argument in saxon?

Comment: Thank you. You have saved my day,